# Flexbox - center horizontally without flex-direction: column

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

It is possible to get something like on the picture with flex box? I can't center right div with flex, and always get left-right in the same row, and third in second row.

[image]

```css
  .table-area {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .table-item{
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: gray;
    flex-basis: 40%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table-area">
    <div class="table-item">
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="table-item">
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="table-item">
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this: (1) Set a fixed height on the container, switch to `flex-direction: column`, and add `justify-content: center`; (2) Use CSS Grid Layout; (3) simply use `transform` https://jsfiddle.net/f1xy3evu/

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B - I think that third solutions is the best for me, because I need to switch order in mobile view, so it's very easy to get this in this case, and I don't know also height of `.table-item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method: Use the `transform` property with the [**`translate`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) function.

```css
.table-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: gray;
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.table-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="table-area">
  <div class="table-item">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```